# Request Error : No ads to show (Admob)

Tags: admob, ads, coronasdk

I created an App on Admob to use in Corona SDK. Previously it was showing ads and I was getting revenue too, but now no ads are displaying and in log the status is "Request Error : No ads to show". Is this error is location based? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: did you change something on adMob like Id?

Comment: no. I didn't change anything except my location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a normal response. It means that there are no ads available for your device at the current location and time. I recommend that you use Admob mediation and include a couple of other ad networks to ensure that you always have ad fill.